# EasyAdmin - password update form gives error on empty password

Tags: php, symfony4, symfony2-easyadmin, easyadmin

I'm using standard Symfony 4 User entity, created by make:auth and EasyAdmin 2.0.4.

When editing existing User, password field is blank (which is good).

On submitting existing User edit form, when leaving password field blank, I get following error:

> Expected argument of type "string", "NULL" given at property path "password".

How to allow EasyAdmin to ignore password field on update, when its value is empty?

Comment: I would imagine it is not expecting you to setup a user without a password. Kinda dangerous in the normal world. Maybe its even insisting you dont

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `empty_data` option to do this. Handle the empty password in your controller.

```
easy_admin:
    entities:
        User:
[...]
            edit:
                    - { property: 'password', type: 'text', type_options: { required: false, empty_data: '' } }
```

Comment: for reference, here's what I did in AdminController:


```
protected function updateAgencyEntity(Agency $entity, Form $editForm)
{
 $postedPassword = $editForm->get('password')->getData();
 if (!empty($postedPassword)) {
  $entity->setPassword($this->passwordEncoder->encodePassword($entity->getUser(), $postedPassword));
 }
 parent::updateEntity($entity);
}
```